# How to get array size in fish shell?

Tags: fish

Is there a way I can get the array size in fish shell?

The exact problem I have at hand is that I would like to do some operations on all array elements except the first one. So I was trying to find the size so that I can loop from 2 to $array_size.

If it is not possible, what is an alternative method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`count` will print the number of elements. But if you want to just skip the first element, you can use [slices](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_lists):

```
> set arr one two three
> echo $arr
one two three
> echo $arr[2..-1]
two three
```

Answer (score 10):

using the `count` command which is a command built into fish.

Example:

```
$ count $PATH
11
```